# Compress file to one cab file

Tags: windows, sharepoint, cmd, cab

I am currently trying to modify one file in a .cab file and then rebuild .cab file using '**makecab.exe**' with all the files including the changed one. Following is the .ddf file, I am using.

**.Set CabinetNameTemplate=Documents.CAB**

**.Set Cabinet=on**

**.Set Compress=on**

**"00000000.000"**

**"10000000.000"**

**"20000000.000"**

**"30000000.000"**

**"40000000.000"**

**"manifest.xml"**

The problem is that three files are generated stored in disk1,disk2 and disk3 folders. The files are trimmed to <1424kb. I want a single cab file. I have tried setting the threshold and size variables.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to edit contents of a.wsp sharepoint package? Unpack .wsp (.cab) and create new modified .wsp (.cab)?

Comment: Its the .stp file. The goal is to export a document library from 2007 farm to 2010 farm. This requires modification of manifest.xml file. The technique works for lists. But for document libraries (with more files) when I try to build the cab file, its split into three files.

Comment: AFAIK makecab.exe can create cab files <2GB, you can try different tool for cab creation.

Comment: The total size of cab was 4KB that I wanted to rebuild. I want to it in the same form and not three pieces of 1KB.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same problem today and luckily I found solution in Microsoft page.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#microsoftmakecabusersguide)

You can add maxdisksize option in .ddf file and it will work!

.Set MaxDiskSize=CDROM